Why am I unable to create a hardlink to a symlink on a macOS HFS+ volume?
This started as a problem with rsync --link-dest which generated a Operation not supported (45) error for every symlink for which it tried to create a hard link.
Some experimentation revealed that this is not specific to rsync and can be duplicated on the command line thus:
touch x
ln -s x x1
ln -P x1 x2
ln: x.2: Operation not supported

A little more information:

MacOS Sonoma 14.5.
The volume in question is on an external drive that came from an older Mac.
This worked on that older Mac (macOS Mojave 10.14.6).
The shell commands above work on the older Mac.
The volume involved is "Mac OS Extended (Case-sensitive, Journaled)" (HFS+).
The above shell commands work on an APFS volume.

I spent some time searching what macOS source code is available and found that creating hard links to symlinks on HFS+ volumes appears to be explicitly disallowed in the HFS code. In macos/hfs/core/hfs_link at line 442 is this code:
/*
 * link vnode operation
 *
 *  IN vnode_t  a_vp;
 *  IN vnode_t  a_tdvp;
 *  IN struct componentname  *a_cnp;
 *  IN vfs_context_t  a_context;
 */
int
hfs_vnop_link(struct vnop_link_args *ap)
{
    ...
    /*
     * For now, return ENOTSUP for a symlink target. This can happen
     * for linkat(2) when called without AT_SYMLINK_FOLLOW.
     */
    if (v_type == VLNK)
        return (ENOTSUP);

Note that there is a check just before this for HFS_STANDARD which is the "non-plus" HFS format and doesn't apply in this case.
Note that I am far from an expert on macOS sources, but this certainly looks like the right code.

IMHO to create hardlink you need command like: ln x1 x2

ln without the -P flag creates a link to the target of the symlink, not the symlink itself.
